# Evenly spaced, justified horizontal nav links: How to remove vertical space in empty :after content

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm trying to achieve horizontal navigation links like this:

```
|--------------------------------------| 
|Link1   L2   LongLink3   Link4   Link5|
|--------------------------------------|
```

Rules:

- Links are evenly spaced (same amount of white space between each link)
- Links can be variable-width
- Collectively the links stretch across the entire available width of their container
- First and last links are lined up with the eges of their container (links are justified)
- Works on IE8+
- CSS/HTML solution, no JavaScript
- Can not set a specific container height or link height
- Can not pre-calculate and hard-code the space between the links (number of links could change later)

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060923/how-to-stretch-html-css-horizontal-navigation-items-evenly-and-fully-across-a/17951253#17951253) almost works--it's so close. But introducing the empty :after content adds unwanted additional vertical space in the nav container (why?). Is there a way to remove the extra vertical space injected by the empty :after content?

HTML that almost works:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>  <!--
    --><li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>  <!--
    --><li><a href="#">BASIC SERVICES</a></li>  <!--
    --><li><a href="#">OUR STAFF</a></li>  <!--
    --><li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li><!--
--></ul><!--
--><h2>next element</h2>
```

CSS that almost works:

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#nav {
    text-align: justify;
    outline: 1px solid grey;
}
#nav:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
#nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: green;
}
#nav a:link {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    padding: 1em 0;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wzrmy/1/) showing what this looks like, as well as the extra vertical space injected by the :after content. The "next element" should be directly below the nav links. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Strange issue.

I assume it has something to do with the fact that inline elements respect whitespace in the markup, though the whitespace is necessary for `text-align:justify` to work, thus it can't be removed.

Since the whitespace is determined by the font's size, you can set the parent's `font-size` to `0`, and then set the children's `font-size` accordingly. It works.. [**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/5XdnC/)

```
#nav {
    text-align: justify;
    outline: 1px solid grey;
    font-size:0;
}
#nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: green;
    font-size:16px;
}
```

Can't think of anything better at the moment. I will let you know if I do.

Comment: I was hoping for something more elegant but this will work, thanks. The main thing is you explained where the extra space was coming from (the parent's font size.), which was a mystery to me. Marking as the solution.

Comment: @mr_reamer is correct in that this fails in IE.  I tested IE10 and IE11.

Answer (score 4):

The trick here is related to the `ul#nav:after` psuedo-element:

```
#nav:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

This inserts an additional element within the nav that has the full width of the container we're trying to fill (the closest ancestor with `position: relative`).  This sets the width of `ul#nav` so that `text-align: justify` will create the desired spacing effect.

The trailing space is the height of the `ul#nav:after` psuedo-element.  Setting `font-size: 0` on the `ul#nav` (as per @Josh Crozier's answer) is an indirect way of forcing the line-height to 0.  That method fails in IE for some reason, but setting the line-height directly appears to work in Chrome, FF, IE10+.  I haven't tested below IE10, but I expect this to work back through IE8 at least.  Here is the full solution:

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#nav {
    text-align: justify;
    outline: 1px solid grey;
    line-height: 0;
}
#nav:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}
#nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: green;
    line-height: 100%;
}
#nav a:link {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    padding: 1em 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found that adding the font-size: 0; to the UL selector breaks it in IE10.