# CSS Anchor tag properties are being ignored completely in #nav li a

Tags: html, css

I'm having a confusing time here trying to figure this one out.  I know I have to be overlooking something here because I've defined anchor properties several times and they have always worked.

Here is a jsfiddle of exactly what I'm working with (I'm actually working with a test nav that I got from this site from another link that I have altered slightly.)

http://jsfiddle.net/LY3Bm/

```
#nav li a {
    font-size: 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    height: 87px;
}
```

I'm stumped completely :\  I pulled out my full website that has this very same type syntax in it for defining properties to an anchor tag inside of a li and inside of a nav and...it works fine.  What am I overlooking?

Thanks!

Comment: There was an illegal character on line 21 of your CSS. Remove it and this works.

Comment: Thank you both, I don't know why this wasn't showing up in dreamweaver -shrugs- but it's all fixed now.  Thank you both again! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you left some kind of illegal character after #nav li 
definition on **line 21** which is breaking the CSS. Shows up as a red dot in the fiddle

```
#nav li {
} *// Some character here

#nav li a {
```

Comment: Haha, well I feel smart :P  I saw that red dot when I pasted it into jsfiddle but I wasn't looking for the problem in there and so I wasn't paying attention!  The dot oddly enough doesn't show up in dreamweaver at all.  I deleted the entire line and types some stuff back in manually, and it's all good now!  Thanks! ^_^