# Horizontally align UL items within parent div with no space on either side?

Tags: html, css

I'm making a navigation menu and have run into the common problem of needing to horizontally align a UL with equal spacing around each list item. However, this list is inside of a div set to a width of 1100px and I need there to be no space on the left or right-hand sides of the div -- the first and last list items need to reach their side of the div.

Here's the unordered list as I have it right now:

```
ul{
            width:100%;
            display:table;
            list-style-type:none;
            padding:0;
            border-spacing:5px;
            li{
                display:table-cell;
                padding:0 30px;
            }
        }
```

And as I said, this unordered list is inside of another div which has its width set to 1100px. What should I do to make the list stretch the full width of the div?

Comment: Can you reproduce your problem in a fiddle?

Comment: Is this the way you are set up? http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/q4peetcj/ I assume you want first and last items to flush against the div?

Comment: Yes, was about to share this: http://jsfiddle.net/9k211ppj/1/

Comment: I want them flush against the div with no extra spacing on left or right side, yes @abhitalks

Comment: They are already flushed. See the red borders, they are already stretching to the end of blue div.

Comment: If you remove the padding on first and last items, then it will be unbalanced.

Comment: @abhitalks as I'm sure you can see the text of the first and last list items do not reach flush with the div, which is what I'm trying to solve

Comment: I'm assuming this probably just isn't possible with table cells

Comment: Here: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/q4peetcj/2/ But, as I said, they are now unbalanced.

Comment: Or you could remove the padding altogether and go with `text-align`: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/q4peetcj/3/

Comment: @TomMaxwell Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17951253/703717) the effect you're for?

Comment: @Danield - yep, that was it! Will give it a try now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Set `text-align:justify` on the container

2) Use a pseudo element to stretch the list items to 100% of the width of the list

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/9k211ppj/3/)**

```css
ul {
  width: 800px;
  text-align: justify;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  background: yellow;
}
ul:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 30px;
  text-align: center;
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div id="explore-nav">
  <ul>
    <li>Example</li>
    <li>Example</li>
    <li>Example</li>
    <li>Example</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Guessing your markup look something like this.

```css
ul {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  border-spacing: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
li {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 0 30px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #EDEDED;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#container {
  width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <ul>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
    <li>Test</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```