# How to make ul nav fill the entire bottom of page evenly (without table display)

Tags: html, css, centering

I realize this question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060923/how-to-stretch-html-css-horizontal-navigation-items-evenly-and-fully-across-a) and the highest upvoted answer was very helpful, however I am having an issue.

Basically I want a `nav` (essential just a `ul`  and its `li`s) to fill the width (or 80% of the width) equally.

The first task is to center the `nav` the second task is to make sure that the items take up equal space.  The other solution on SO proposes a bit of a hack, inserting `content: ""` after the `ul`.  This works great, along with the other css rules I show below, when all `li`s are one word.  However, for two word `li`s I get the effect achieved in my screen shot here:

[image: one the text is spread quite wide between the two words]  If there is not a smooth way to remove that space, is there at least some sort of hack to make that space smaller that someone can think of? 
I made a jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9Le7fdkc/) but it doesn't really illustrate how bad the problem is.

Thanks a lot

**HTML:**

```
    <article class="main home">
        <img class="heroLogo" src="media/TM-Logo-4.png">
            <nav>
                <div class="menuIcon"></div>
                <ul>
    <li><a href="http://www.google.com">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.google.com">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.google.com">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Two longWords</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.google.com">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.google.com">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.google.com">One</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
    </article>
```

**CSS:**

```
.menuIcon {
    display: none;
}

nav, nav:hover {
    width: 80%;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    text-align: center;
}

nav ul, nav:hover ul, nav ul.clicked, nav ul.none {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    text-align: justify;
}

nav ul:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}

nav li {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simplify your CSS and use `display: inline-block` - it's quite useful, and give the `<li>`s a percentage width value. Check this out (if you know the amount of list items you will have)

CSS

```
.menuIcon {display: none}
nav {width: 100%; position: fixed; left: 0; bottom: 0; font-size: 1.2em}
nav ul {text-align: center; padding: 0; width: 80%; margin: 0 auto}
nav li {display: inline-block; width: 14%; margin: 0}
```

HTML

```
<article class="main home">
  <img class="heroLogo" src="media/TM-Logo-4.png">
  <nav>
    <div class="menuIcon"></div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://www.google.com">One</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.google.com">One</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.google.com">One</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Two longWords</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.google.com">One</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.google.com">One</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.google.com">One</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, it seems that the solution is rather trivial:
Deleting  `"text-align: justify;"` will probably fix you up.

A longer answer would describe how the the `width: 100%` will spread the LI's and the text will then full justify to fill the space it was allocated... but I'm too lazy to write it.

Comment: without text justify the `lis` are not spread evenly throughout their container.

Comment: Nevertheless... This is why there is space in your text. You asked the question ;) To ensure that each button takes equal space, set the li width to 100/7, ie li { width:14% }... like @thePav suggests