# Spaces between links are un-even

Tags: html, css

I've used this solution: [How to stretch html / css horizontal navigation items evenly and fully across a specified container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060923/how-to-stretch-html-css-horizontal-navigation-items-evenly-and-fully-across-a)
Answered by Felix.

But although I have done this, per se, it does work but there are a few links are have un-even spaces between them. I have no reason why, and I honestly do not know the solution. I've tried going through and everything seems fine. Lastly how, could I specify where to start this? I have a title and it's overlapping it.

```css
#nav {
    display: table;
    height: 87px;
    width: 70%;
}

#nav li {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 87px;
    line-height: 87px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 12.5%;  /* (100 / numItems)% */
}

.link {
    min-width: 60px;
    min-height: 30px;
    background: #666;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.2s;
    -webkit-user-select:none;
    -moz-user-select:none;
    -ms-user-select:none;
    font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Franklin Gothic', 'ITC Franklin Gothic', Arial, sans-serif;
    position: absolute;
    user-select: none;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -15px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-right: 8px;
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    white-space: nowrap; 
}

.link:hover {
    background: #999;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Franklin Gothic', 'ITC Franklin Gothic', Arial, sans-serif;
    border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
}

.link:active {
    background: #999;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Franklin Gothic', 'ITC Franklin Gothic', Arial, sans-serif;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    #nav li {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
    }
}

.menubar {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10%;
    left: 10%;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: auto;
    border: none;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
    background: #666;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2) ;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2) ;
    height: 60px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="menubar">
 <div class="links">
  <ul id="nav">
   <li><a href="/index.php" class="link">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="/forums" class="link">Forums</a></li>
   <li><a href="/aboutus.php" class="link">About Us</a></li>
   <li><a href="/submit.php" class="link">Submit</a></li>
   <li><a href="/downloads.php" class="link">Downloads</a></li>
   <li><a href="/archive.php" class="link">Archive</a></li>
   <li><a href="/other.php" class="link">Other</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

Let me know if you need the container code, not sure if required.

Comment: What are "*un-even spaces*"?

Comment: They appear uneven **because they all have the same widths** — check the computed dimensions using inspector. But since the text in each link can be of variable lengths, it will appear as if they have uneven spacing between them. If cross browser compatibility is not much of a big issue, I strongly recommend using CSS flexbox instead.

Comment: @Terry Would you happen to know what browsers CSS flexbox aren't compatible with? Are there any work arounds?

Comment: @Tiny that would be the spaces between the downloads and archive button.

Comment: It is actually quite widely supported (if you also consider browsers that support the (now) outdated flexbox specification): http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox. For fallback you will have to combine feature detection (e.g. Modernizr) and a backup layout strategy.

Comment: @Terry could you give me an example of code, I've looked around and tried around but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have asked for a CSS flexbox-based solution, I have made some changes to your code to implement this. A quick list of changes I have made:

- Remove all `display: table` properties in your CSS
- Declare `#nav` as a flex item, and ensure that wrapping is disabled (so content do not wrap to a new line)
- Declare `#nav li` as children of a flex item, and allow them to grow using `flex-grow: 1`. This will allow these elements to expand as of when necessary (i.e. when there is unallocated space in the parent element after computing all the widths of `<li>` elements.
- Removed absolute positioning in the `<a>` links, because that takes the element out of document flow preventing proper height computation. Also, declare them as block-level elements (so they fill up the parent `<li>`

For visual improvement (but not necessary for functionality), I suggest using a transparent border on un-hovered links. This prevents jittering of the hovered elements (which as a 1px border being applied).

Without furhter ado, here is the code snippet:

```css
#nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  width: 70%;
  list-style: none;
}

#nav li {
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.link {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  min-width: 60px;
  min-height: 30px;
  background: #666;
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -webkit-user-select:none;
  -moz-user-select:none;
  -ms-user-select:none;
  font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Franklin Gothic', 'ITC Franklin Gothic', Arial, sans-serif;
  user-select: none;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 8px;
  padding-right: 8px;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap; 
}

.link:hover {
  background: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Franklin Gothic', 'ITC Franklin Gothic', Arial, sans-serif;
  border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
}

.link:active {
  background: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Franklin Gothic', 'ITC Franklin Gothic', Arial, sans-serif;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  #nav {
    flex-wrap: wrap;  
  }
  #nav li {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.menubar {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10%;
  left: 10%;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  border: none;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
  background: #666;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2) ;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2) ;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="menubar">
 <div class="links">
  <ul id="nav">
   <li><a href="/index.php" class="link">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="/forums" class="link">Forums</a></li>
   <li><a href="/aboutus.php" class="link">About Us</a></li>
   <li><a href="/submit.php" class="link">Submit</a></li>
   <li><a href="/downloads.php" class="link">Downloads</a></li>
   <li><a href="/archive.php" class="link">Archive</a></li>
   <li><a href="/other.php" class="link">Other</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I appreciate it, and all is looking good. However, I have run into a little trouble! I actually have a title on the left side of the div, so I was trying to use   flex-end but it doesn't seem to be working at all. Appreciate the help Terry.

Comment: Update your question to reflect that. Without the markup I can't propose a fix.