# Justified horizontal HTML Navigation with actual stretched <li>'s and no space inbetween

Tags: html, css, navigation

id like to have a justified horizontal HTML navigation, where the li elements are actually stretched.

Basically the second solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17951253/4597849

But so, that the li's have an auto padding, meaning they fill up the space inbetween, so that i can give them a backgroundcolor.

Is this even possible without JS?

Comment: Why padding?  Just set the width as `calc(100% / <# of elements>)`

Comment: forgot to mention, the amount of items has to be variable, so css doesnt know the # of elements

Comment: and the length of the li's may vary. this should be part of the question. i cant edit though :/

Comment: Do you need to support older browsers or just current - 1?

Comment: It should work on IE8 upwards